# Error : Cannot read property fetch. Using jest-expo with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

> **TypeError**: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
>
> ```
>   at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:4:8
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:466:3)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-expo/src/setup.js:97:348)
> ```

Got error while running tests with jest-expo. If anyone have solution please share.

Comment: share your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is a guess without a code snippet, but looking at [what `fetch.js` looked like at the time](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/7a692dc519a3a110526a26c7e252f99991510c2a/fetch.js), the `undefined` value whose `fetch` property we can't read is the variable `self` (see line 1), which was meant to be set to the `this` context (see line 466).

Therefore, it seems that `fetch.js` is expecting to run in an environment where `this` refers to the `window`, but `jest-expo`, being a testing tool, is running it in some other environment, probably in strict mode where `this` is `undefined`.